# Why do we bless only the 10th Rabbi in the community after reading the Megillah?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The bracha after finishing the Megillah starts:

*Harav Esri Veinu* - The tenth rabbi among us

Why bless just the 10th rabbi. Aren't the other 9 as worthy?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 2):

You are mistranslating veinu - if it meant among us, it would have said *veinenu*. The proper translation is "The tenth Rav, the son of (all of us)."

When you have 10 rabbanim, you have ten sarei asarot, which means you have at least a hundred people and asarah batlanim (the rabbanim), making you chayiv to have a beis din because you fulfill the minimum requirements of a village.

We bless the tenth rabbi because he is considered to be the child of the entire community, as he defines the city in which he lives. As chazal says: It takes a village!